# Sum values of column with type character

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a column `valorout` with this type of values:

```
652.000000
133.000000   
163.000000  
...
```

---

So, I want the sum of the column `valorout` grouped by `duplicated`.

**QUERY**

```
select sum(valorout) from trans GROUP BY(duplicated);
```

**ERROR**

```
Error in query: ERROR: function sum(character) does not exist
LINE 1: select sum(valorout) from trans GROUP BY(duplica...
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What I need to change to solve this problem?

Comment: What is your data type for valorout column?

Comment: @nightingalez character(50)

Comment: You can't do math on text fields.  What database engine are you using?

Comment: THe hint is clear,convert the column to some numeric type.

Comment: You have to cast `valorout` column

Comment: Do **not** store numbers in `varchar` columns. Use `numeric` (or `integer`) instead. Additionally: you almost *never* want `char`, if you need a character datatype use `varchar` or `text`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer might be

```
select sum(valorout::decimal) from trans GROUP BY(duplicated);
```

Your type is varchar(50), you need to cast it to decimal / integer / float for SUM to work